# Update draggables background on button click according to which draggable is in it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

**Answer**

For anyone else trying to do this, I was able to do it by adding an empty class to the droppable before the .click function with

```
$("#game1drop4").droppable ({
    accept: "#game1img4",
    drop: function(e,ui) {
      $(this).addClass("correct");
    }
    });
```

Then after the click function I checked if the droppable had the empty class and if it did I added a new class with the background change. Like this:

```
$("#submitG1").click( function check() {

    if ($("#game1drop1").hasClass("correct")) {
      $("#game1drop1").addClass("iscorrect");
      $("#game1img1").draggable("disable");
    }
    else {
      $(this).animate({left:0,top:0});
    }
```

so I'm trying to build a game where the user has to place images (draggables) in the correct order to move on to the next level. I want the user to be able to place all of the images and then click submit and if the images are placed in the right droppable have the droppable background change color. I have found away to do change the background on the drop of the picture but have been unable to get it to update if the image(draggable) is already in the droppable. I have posted my code on fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L36fLoa8/5/) however it looks a little funky without the draggable pictures. '

To identify if the right draggable was in the right droppable, I assigned each draggable and ID in the html, then in the js under each droppable I used "accept: "#game1img1"" to tell it to identify which draggable to accept. Might not be the most efficient way to do it but its the only way I could figure out.

Here is the code that it think matters most

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(function () {
// everything with the class "draggable" will be made draggable  


  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    //makes all draggables revert to their orginal postition if their drop is not valid
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".droppable").droppable()

   $("#game1img1").draggable({
    snap: ".droppablep",
    snapTolerance: 25
  });
  $(".instructionhider").click(function () {
      $(".instructions").hide();       
    });
   // Checks if object being dropped is correct for all droppables
   $("#submitG1").click( function() {

  $("#game1drop1").droppable ({
   accept: "#game1img1", 
    drop: function(e,ui) {
      $(this).addClass("correct");
      $('#correct1').addClass('.correctText');
    }
    });


  if $(ui.draggable.attr("id") === (this).attr("id")).droppable) {
    $(this).addClass("correct");
   }
   else {
      revert: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
            top : 0,
            left : 0,
           return !event;
      }

    });


  $("#game1drop3").droppable ({
    accept: "#game1img3",
    drop: function(e,ui) {
      $(this).addClass("correct")
    }
    });


  $("#game1drop4").droppable ({
    accept: "#game1img4",
    drop: function(e,ui) {
      $(this).addClass("correct");
    }
    });

 function submit() { if ($("#game1drop1").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop2").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop3").hasClass("correct") && $("#game1drop4").hasClass("correct")) {
      $(".completion").css("visibility","visible");
  };
};
});
```

Comment: Hi, Regarding your previous question which was asking 2 questions in it - You didn't have to delete it, there is an [edit] option below the question, you can always edit your question and update it...

Comment: regarding this question - *"if the images are placed in the right droppable"* - How do we know which is the right droppable..? What is the rule..? *"unable to get it to update if the image(draggable) is already in the droppable"* - What do you mean by update..? BTW, the image in fiddle is broken...

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I could edit the post i'm pretty new to the site. I added my method for identifying which draggable belonged in which droppable. About the images, I couldn't figure out how to upload images from my desktop to fiddle so they could be accessed by fiddle.

Comment: You should upload the image in some free image hosting site and specify the url in it's `src`... You can actually edit the question and upload images from your computer to it, but I believe it required a bit of rep... But that isn't an issue, can you clarify what you meant by *"unable to get it to update if the image(draggable) is already in the droppable"*..?

Comment: I updated the link so everything works now. if you drag the first row of gray squares up to the first row of droppables, in corresponding order. Then hit submit the backgrounds do not update to green, however if you go back and click the draggable and drop it back into the same droppable the background will turn green. I am trying to make it so you don't have to go back up and click the droppable to make the background green.